# K8 / Cert-Manager / Errors and Possible YAML misconfiguration

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, cert-manager

I am attempting to get cert-manager working with Let's Encrypt and I am running into some interesting errors, such as cert-manager not being able to access resources. I am also seeing two certificates and two certificaterequests when I would only expect one. I've attached some pictures of logging and output from the certs and cert requests. I've tried quite a few adjustments but I seem to be spinning my wheels. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
---
kind: Secret
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: coreyperkinsdev-production-clusterissuer-acme
  namespace: default
data:
  coreyperkinsdevacmedns.json: 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
  tls.key: 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
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: coreyperkins-deployment
  labels:
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: coreyperkins-frontend
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: coreyperkins-frontend
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: coreyperkins-frontend
          image: coreyperkinsdev.azurecr.io/www:52
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "100m"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: coreyperkinsdev-acr-secret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: coreyperkins-service
  labels:
    app: coreyperkins-frontend
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 80
    name: http
  selector:
    app: coreyperkins-frontend
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: coreyperkinsdev-production-clusterissuer
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    email: corey.perkins@gmail.com    
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: coreyperkinsdev-production-clusterissuer-acme
    solvers:
      - dns01:
          acmedns:
            host: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
            accountSecretRef:
              name: coreyperkinsdev-production-clusterissuer-acme
              key: coreyperkinsdevacmedns.json
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: coreyperkinsdev-production-certificate
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  secretName: coreyperkinsdev-production-clusterissuer-acme
  issuerRef: 
    name: coreyperkinsdev-production-clusterissuer
    kind: ClusterIssuer    
  commonName: coreyperkins.dev
  dnsNames:
    - coreyperkins.dev
    - '*.coreyperkins.dev'
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: coreyperkinsdev-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: coreyperkinsdev-production-clusterissuer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - coreyperkins.dev
    - '*.coreyperkins.dev'
    secretName: coreyperkinsdev-production-clusterissuer-acme
  rules:
  - host: www.coreyperkins.dev
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /?(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: coreyperkins-service
          servicePort: 5000
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: coreyperkinsdev-ng-cm
data:
  http-snippet: |
    types {
      module;
    }
---
```

Comment: Hey, I would highly recommend you to avoid placing images of code as it does not meet stack guidelines and its very difficult to read. Can you please past them as text?

Comment: Can you provide outputs from `kubectl describe clusterissuer` and perform short troubleshoooting as described [here](https://cert-manager.io/docs/faq/acme/) such as `describe order`, `get challenges` and `describe challenge`

Comment: @acid_fuji the images are output, not code